# Computationally efficient way to check if large number is divisible by 3

Tags: algorithm, performance, primes, division

If

M<sub>p</sub>=2<sup>p</sup>-1 is prime ⇒

⇒ 2<sup>p</sup>-2⋮6 or 2<sup>p</sup>⋮6 ⇒

⇒ 2<sup>p-1</sup>-1⋮3 or 2<sup>p-1</sup>⋮3 ⇒

⇒ 2<sup>n</sup>-1⋮3 or 2<sup>n</sup>⋮3, n=p-1

In order to pick huge values for p to test if M<sub>p</sub> is a prime number, I believe this is a good preliminary test before going with the computationally expensive Lucas-Lehmer test.

But what is the fastest, most efficient way to test if two numbers, 2<sup>n</sup>-1 and 2<sup>n</sup>, are divisible by 3?

Other info that we can use from this is that n always ends in 0, 2, 6 or 8 (because p=n+1 is a prime). Maybe it helps in some way.

Comment: PHP has a remainder function '%' which from `5%2 = 1` whereby 1 is the remainder from 5 cut into 2 (2x2 = 4, 5-4 = 1, remainder is 1) . Can you use something like this that can give `33033%3 = 0` = can be divisible by three?

Comment: 2^n is never divisible by 3, as by definition it is only divisible by 2^x for 0<=x<=n

Comment: Since you seem to already have the decimal representation of your number: A number is divisible by 3, is the sum of its decimal digits is divisible by 3. Recursion can be applied.

Answer (score 4):

It's easy to prove:

```
2^n mod 3
== 1 if n is even
== 2 if n is odd
```

using mathematical induction.

So 2<sup>n</sup> is never divisible by 3, and 2<sup>n</sup>-1 is divisible by 3 if and only if n is even.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The problem is that n is always even in the above case(see last line).

Comment: Well then, it seems there is no problem. You don't need to compute anything. `n` is always even, so `2^n-1` is always divisible by 3 and `2^n` never is. The most computationally efficient code possible is the code you never have to run.

Answer (score 0):

Sum the digits, if result is dividable by 3 then it is.
ea

25681 = 2+5+6+8+3 = 24   (=2+4) = 6 is dividable.

Answer (score 0):

if u're dealing with `bigint`s and the inputs are already in an `ASCII` `string` format of some sort, you can simply :

1. high-speed scrub away all instances of **`0, 3, 6, and 9`** via `regex ::`**`gsub()`** (or equiv.),

   - measure the string **`length() / len()`** at that point,
   - count # of instances of **`2, 5, and 8`**
2. sum up the values of the 2 sub-bullet points, then **`mod % 3`**

This works no matter how large the big-int is.

But yes, like others have mentioned already, no point to run it through this algorithm if you already knew that the input is an integer power of an integer base, and if the base itself isn't divisible by 3, then neither would any of its integer powers.